# Merge/rebase workflow

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I am in the process of changing my git-merge-workflow and encountered following problem:

Up to now, i have been merging (--no-ff) my changes on the `develop` branch back to `master` whenever i released a new version. This generated a new merge-commit containing the history (--log) of all the `develop`-commits.
I realized that this is sub-optimal, and want to actually do fast-forward merges from my `develop` branch to `master` (having changed my commit-messages on `develop` to reflect my changes in a "cleaner" way).

My current problem: The most recent commit on `master` is a still a merge-commit from the last time, due to that I can't do an ff-merge from `develop` to `master` now, since the 2 branches "diverged" (the merge-commit is missing on `develop`).

My idea to solve this would have been, being on develop: `git rebase master`, which would pull in this merge-commit, and then enable me to do a `git merge develop` on master.
But would this generate a new commit on `develop` (this particular merge-commit) or will git be smart enough to recognize that the changes of this merge-commit are already part of `develop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rebase master` while on `develop` will work fine for your purposes.

If your branches are currently like this:

```
A-B-C-D-E <-- master
       /
  F-G-H-I-J <-- develop
```

then they'll wind up like this (because `I-J` is the only bit not reachable from `E`):

```
A-B-C-D-E <-- master
         \
          I'-J' <-- develop
```

which will then fast-forward merge back into master like this:

```
A-B-C-D-E-I'-J' <-- master
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should allow it to work. Another way you can tackle this of course is to remove your develop branch completely at the next merge to master in case rebasing failed. Then just branch off a new develop from master and rebase from that point onwards.

At my previous company we tried to switch our workflow from merging to rebasing as well. But it ended up having all sorts of weird issues from merging of different branches. It just felt cleaner and safer to start anew on the develop branch directly from master.